# Authenticate with SSSD in multiple domains in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I was able to successfully [follow this document to get `sssd` to work with my Active Directory domain](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html), but I was sad to learn that `sssd` does not support authenticating with external trusts.

I read that you can actually join multiple domains with the assistance of `krb5` and `samba` (?) so I tried to do so by copying my existing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and edited it to reflect the additional domain, so that it starts like this:

```
[global]

workgroup = ANOTHER
client signing = yes
client use spnego = yes
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
realm = ANOTHER.EXAMPLE.COM
security = ads
```

I then edited `/etc/krb5.conf` to add my new domain `ANOTHER.EXAMPLE.COM` under `[realms]` section like so:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = HI.EXAMPLE.COM
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
         rdns=false

        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]


ANOTHER.EXAMPLE.COM = {
        kdc = another.example.com
        admin_server = another.example.com
        master_kdc = another.example.com
        default_domain = another.example.com
}
```

Finally I did `kinit -V my.user@ANOTHER.EXAMPLE.COM` and it asked for password and successfully authenticated. I then did `net ads join -U my.user /etc/samba/smb_another.conf`, again entered my password, and got the following:

```
Using short domain name -- ANOTHER
Joined 'SERVER9' to dns domain 'another.example.com'
No DNS domain configured for server9. Unable to perform DNS Update.
DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

Ok, not great, but I've seen this kind of error before and it still worked. So then I try `getent passwd my.user@ANOTHER.EXAMPLE.COM`.

It hangs for like 20 seconds and comes back empty-handed.

Any suggestions or tips, or advice on whether this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to use the UPN to login. After trying `getent passwd` with that, it works!